# What is the equivalent CentOS for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5?

Tags: centos, rhel, version

According to [CentOS website](http://wiki.centos.org/RedHat), they use the source code from Red Hat, but I am not clear about what version of Red Hat source code is being used to build each version of CentOS.

Is there a numeric equivalent? For example, is CentOS 6.5 equivalent/based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5?

Answer (score 19):

CentOS 6.5 is based on RHEL 6.5; prior to CentOS 7, CentOS versions exactly match RHEL versions. The pattern changed with CentOS 7, which uses something like a build number: CentOS 7 (1406) is based on RHEL 7.0, CentOS 7 (1503) is based on RHEL 7.1, etc. You'll find all the details on the [CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/Download) (look for the "Archived Versions" section).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just noticed that http://wiki.centos.org/Download includes the version of RedHat used to create each version of CentOS. That's great info.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. CentOS uses the same major and minor release numbers as the RHEL version they are rebuilding.